# swift, embed ui view controller with navigation controller to allow for back button

Tags: swift, xcode, controller, navigation

I am trying to get a back button on my MyServiceTypeSelector() controller so that after i present MyServiceTypeSelector() I can go back to the BRPServiceSelector() controller , how can i do this ? do i some how need to embed it with a nav controller and if so i am not using storyboards so it would need to be done programmatically?

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit

class BRPServiceSelector: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupViews()



}



let businessAccountLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Business Account"
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()







lazy var serviceSelectorButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.setTitle("Select A Service Type?", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentServiceSelector), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

    return button
}()


func presentServiceSelector(){

    let msts = MyServiceTypeSelector()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: msts)
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)







let containerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    return v
}()





let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let v = UIScrollView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    return v
}()


func setupViews(){

    containerView.addSubview(serviceSelectorButton)

    serviceSelectorButton.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 50, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 220, height: 25)

    serviceSelectorButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if you want the VC in the navigation stack then `push` it onto the stack instead of presenting it. presenting is normally used for modal windows and they dont usually have navigation bars. `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: great, i put it as the answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want the VC in the navigation stack then push it onto the stack instead of presenting it. presenting is normally used for modal windows and they dont usually have navigation bars.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```